# Idle3 Path Browser Not Showing All Paths

Tags: python-3.x

I'm playing around with python, and I added '/home/[username]/Python' with

```
sys.path.append()
```

When I output the path using sys, the new path shows up (though it doesn't seem to work correctly), but when I use Idles Path Browser, it doesn't show the added path. Iv'e reset idle, and the path change persists between runs, so I don't think it's being reset. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The path browser uses IDLE's `sys.path`, not that of the subprocess. For example, run `idle3 -n` to start IDLE without a subprocess. Now changes to `sys.path` will show up in the path browser.

Comment: @eryksun Note that the subprocess mode will be removed (I think in 3.4/5). A bug report is required I think.